# Google Compute Engine (GCE) email delivery solution HOW TO?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a project uploaded on google cloud and on that project whenever some one registers he gets an email saying "welcome".
When this project was hosted on a web server(not google cloud server) it was working fine and emails would go on registration.
But since the project has been moved to google cloud the email services have stopped.All the other functionalities are working fine.

IS there something iam missing out ,or does google want us to get a email domain from google.

coding language- cake php
database       - Mysql

I have already unblocked ports 25,587,465 ,but that also did not resolve the issue

Please advise and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have to use SendGrid to use other email than gmail.

As describe in this document:

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail

There are examples listed there as well.

Comment: i have a gmail account but that is also not working,the email account linkd to my GCE

Comment: I have just followed the postfix example on a GCE instance https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail#postfixsendgrid and it seems to work fine.

Comment: what did you do in step 6 .How did you do it without a sendgrid username and password.In step 6 it asks you for one

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I followed all the instructions in the document, which includes signing up with SendGrid (free).

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a relay **outside** of GCE and configured it to listen on TCP/588 (non standard SMTP port) and then configured all of my GCE instances to relay to that host over TCP/588. That's been working great for months now.